# virustotal Scan URL

Tags: python

I was using the virustotal API this is the code

```
import requests

def scanurl(scan_url):
    url = "https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/urls"

    payload = { "url": scan_url }
    headers = {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "x-apikey": "redacted",
        
    }

    response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    id = response.json().get('data', '').get('id', '')
    print(id)
    headers = {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "x-apikey": "redacted",
    }
    url = "https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/urls/" + id

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(response.text)

scanurl("https://www.youtube.com/")
```

and I got this error:

```json
u-dbae2d0204aa489e234eb2f903a0127b17c712386428cab12b86c5f68aa75867-1701503514
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Wrong URL id: u-dbae2d0204aa489e234eb2f903a0127b17c712386428cab12b86c5f68aa75867-1701503514",
        "code": "BadRequestError"
    }
}
```

I have tried the API testing web site of virustotal; I mean the documentation site but the same response.

Comment: Is that your real API key? You need to redact it from your question and change it now. You shouldn't post your key in a public site.